# How do I access and change the var attribute in both classes in C#?

Tags: c#, class

```
public class Structure
{
    public int var; 
}

class SolarPanel : Structure //first inherited class
{
    var=1;
    
}

class WindTurbine : Structure //second inherited class
{
    var=2;
}
```

I want to change the attribute inherited from the father class independently in the two subclasses, but I don't know how to do that, the problem is also that I don't know how to search for my problem.

Comment: When you create a new instance of the base classes, they will have independent values, so the variable won't change in both when you change one

Comment: That's not an _attribute_ it's a _field_.  And `var` is a keyword in C#.  You can refer to a field  named `var` with the syntax `@var` if you're reluctant to rename it.

Comment: Also, you cannot set a field in class scope. You need to set it from a constructor or method.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the property static it will exist on the base class, rather than object.

I'd also recommend changing the name from `var` ;)

Another approach - would be to have another class that is consumed by both - this would need to be registered as a singleton (i.e. only one copy of the class exists).